# Heroku Postgresql Lost Data

Tags: postgresql, heroku, django-rest-framework, heroku-postgres

I have a Heroku app which was a hobby dyno, I can pay it anymore, well not for now, but I notice that a lot of data was lost.

¿Is that a process that Heroku made when the dyno goes from hobby to free plan?

It was a problem because there's a lot of production data in the database

Comment: What did Heruko say when you asked them about this issue?

Comment: Did you also downgrade your [Heroku Postgres plan](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql)? Are you within the storage and row count limits of the plan you are using (currently 10,000 rows and 1GB for the free tier)?

Comment: Heroku doesn't give support tickets to free dynos, that's why they can't help me. I have 9000 rows left so I think that's ok

Comment: It took me about 3 seconds to find the issue, it's clearly documented: Row Limit
10,000 https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql

Comment: Yes the limit is 10,000 but I only use 1,000 so I think that is not the problem